# Showing Arabic Mixed with English Correctly via CSS

Tags: html, css, arabic, bidi

I want to show `HI('مرحبا','75 Apples for you')` in the browser

This is how it looks(from Chrome):

[image: This is how it looks(from Chrome)]

but it should look like this(from VSCode):

[image: This is how it should look(from VSCode)]

It is the word `HI` then `(` then the word`'` `مرحبا` `'` then `,` then `'75 Apples for you'` then `)`
it should show them in the same order, but what happens is that it merges the Arabic word `مرحبا` (without quotes) with the English word

I can't change the raw text as a workaround, I need a way to show them correctly via CSS
any workaround? I tried all the values of the unicode-bidi CSS property, doesn't solve this problem

Comment: Please add a [repro] for debugging details

Comment: I provided the text, just print it and see it from the browser `HI('مرحبا','75 Apples for you')`
it should look is the image provided

Answer (score 2):

Via Html

Use `<bdi>` Element  ( put Arabic words in  Element Tag)

Like that : `<p> HI( <bdi>'مرحبا'</bdi> , '75 Apples for you' ) </p>`

Via Css

```
<div class="para"> HI(
        <p class="p">'مرحبا'</p>
        <p class="p">,'75 Apples for you'</p>)</div>

.p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I can't change the raw string, I get the string `HI('مرحبا','75 Apples for you')` from log file
maybe change it programmatically, like making an algorithm that detects the Arabic text and replace is with a version of it with <p> HTML tag or something
I'm looking for easier approach that uses CSS only, i know VS Code uses some kind of Chromium renderer that uses CSS, so I think they are using CSS to solve this